# Android auto backup not working on different devices

Tags: java, android, android-backup-service

I'm implementing android autobackup using 
`android:allowbackup="true"`

It works fine when tested on the same device, data is restored correctly.

When testing on a second device, signed into the same Google Play account, the data is not restored on installing the app.

I assume this is how autobackup is meant to work.

Both devices have backup turned on via device settings, and logged into the same Google account.

On 'device two' I can see the backup log from the 1st device via Google Drive>backups>App data>appname.

I expect that the data should be restored on another device using the same Google play account.

Answer (score 4):

It's not supposed to work like this. Each device has a separate backup set. You can restore an existing device set to another device, only when the initial device setup wizard is run. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) for more details, especially in the section Restore Schedule, which says:

> During the initial device setup wizard, the user is shown a list of available backup datasets and is asked which one to restore the data from. Whichever backup dataset is selected becomes the ancestral dataset for the device. The device can restore from either its own backups or the ancestral dataset. The device prioritize its own backup if backups from both sources are available. If the user didn't go through the device setup wizard, then the device can restore only from its own backups.

The fact that you can see the other device's backup folder in your drive application does not mean that you can restore from, or backup to it. It's as if it's another folder.

Comment: thanks George for explaining. Looks like I misunderstood the functionality and have more work to do.

Comment: I think that what you need the ability to maintain a user profile server-side. One  lightweight approach to implement this might be through the Firebase Realtime Database mechanism.

Comment: thanks George and Paul, you guys saved a lot of time for me. This is really good explanation. Thanks again.

Comment: What is "initial device setup wizard"? How to run this wizard? where can I find it?

Comment: @OleksandrAlbul It's what you see when you boot the device for the first time or after a factory reset. It'll ask you whether you want to restore data from another device at some point.